# How to Display Region form inside outlook office 2013 application?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

how to display  a new separate region  form or user control inside outlook  using new Custom tab with new button or built in tab  with new Custom  groub

Answer (score 1):

The forum region is associated with a specific message class, to display a form region you need to create a new Outlook item with the associated message class. Also you may use the [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863603.aspx) property - a boolean value that indicates whether the form region is visible or hidden.

Also you may find the following forum threads helpful:

- [Display Form Region with a button from Ribbon Outlook Add-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505586/display-form-region-with-a-button-from-ribbon-outlook-add-in)
- [Show FormRegion from Ribbon Button Click Event](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4864b91b-87a5-422b-b88c-1726ee952410/show-formregion-from-ribbon-button-click-event?forum=vsto)
- [Show/Hide Adjoining Form Region In Appointmen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d15f3ebc-6dcc-4a40-982c-066ed540b826/showhide-adjoining-form-region-in-appointment?forum=vsto)
- [Force a form region to reload/refresh](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b33d6dd0-e2f7-47cc-83a9-646971d69baf/force-a-form-region-to-reloadrefresh?forum=outlookdev)